# Can I use power supply intended for LED to power CCTV cameras

Tags: electrical, power-supply, cctv

I have 8 WiFi CCTV and for all, power lines converge at the same spot in the house. Instead of using 8 adapters (12v-12w) that came with, can I hook them to 12v-120w ps unit which I originally bought for LED strips? I'm not sure how amps come into play here.

Comment: if they are wired in parallel you are good to go

Comment: Watts is volts times amps, assuming the load remains constant.

Comment: How long are the DC power lines going to be? Above a few dozen feet the voltage drop due to resistance will be obnoxious.